# Camera focus ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, camera

I have crash message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Setting focusPointOfInterest is not supported by this device.  Use isFocusPointOfInterestSupported'

after code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
}
```

Is there any way to make focus like in ***Camera roll***?

Comment: I don't think you really understand the concept of focus.. You have to set the focus before capturing the photo, you can't do that afterwards

Comment: Where do you see capturing photo code in my question?

Comment: Wait, am I getting this right: you want to set the focus point of a photo in camera roll?

Comment: I want to set focus like in Camera roll..

Comment: Read the crash message: “Setting focusPointOfInterest is not supported by this device.”  That means **no**, there is no way to “make focus like in Camera roll” **on this device**.  On other devices, you can set the focus.  On this device, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of answers, but this should help you out.

You need to convert the touch point from your touches began or touch gesture to a 0-1 scale.

So, check if your device has focus and then convert the point:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get device reference...

    if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported]) {
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.myCameraView];
        float newX = point.x / self.myCameraView.frame.size.width;
        float newY = point.y / self.myCameraView.frame.size.height;
        [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(newX, newY)];
    }
    else {
        // Focus not supported
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `setFocusPointOfInterest` is accepted by using `[device focusPointOfInterestSupported]` as **not all iOS devices support it**, and if I remember right it differs by front/back camera as well

Answer (score 0):

What JoeCortoPassi said.

so basically do a if loop to check if [device focusPointOfInterestSupported] returns true then do your  [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(100, 100)];

EDIT:

code would be something like:

```
if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported]){
    [device setFocusPointOfInterest:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
}else{
     // Not supported
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: You have to normalize the CGPoint to a 0-1 scale. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html